# Well definition of measure on measurable spaces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I don't really understand the consistency of the following definition of measure :

> Given a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, a measure on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ is a map $\mu : \Sigma \to [0,\infty]$ which satisfies
>
> 1. The empty set has zero measure, *i.e.* $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$
> 2. $\mu$ is countably-additive, it means that for any family $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of pairwise disjoint measurable sets, the measure of countable union is the sum of measures :
>      $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(A_n) $$

But, the second condition assumes that the sum converges unconditionally ? Since if I want to reindex my family, I want the measure be the same...

However, $[0,\infty]$ with usual operations is a commutative monoid, hence we are able to define finite sum and we must show that any family of elements of $[0,\infty]$ is unconditional convergent with respect to the Alexandrov's topology on $[0,\infty]$ :/

I don't see how to proceed, in order to legitimate the above definition. Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the summands $\mu(A_n)$ are all positive, the summation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(A_n)$ automatically converges absolutely. Therefore, rearrangements give the same sum, and there are no problems.

Comment: And if every set $A_n$ has an $\infty$ measure ?

Comment: If all (or even just one) of $\mu(A_n)=\infty$, then the sum is infinite, no matter how it is rearranged.